# Tidyverse merging to datasets on most recent dates

Tags: r, date, merge, tidyverse

In R, I have a two data sets with dates that I am attempting to merge.  The first is the environmental conditions that have start_dates and stop_dates.  Interval time lengths irregular, ranging from a day to a year.  The second data set is events that have a given date.  I would like to merge them so that I know the environmental conditions that existed during each event.

In the below example, the merged result should be a data set should be the Event_data with a new column showing the weather at each date.

```
require(tidyverse)

( Envir_data = data.frame(envir_start_date=as.Date(c("2017-05-31","2018-01-17", "2018-02-03"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                        envir_end_date=as.Date(c("2018-01-17", "2018-01-20", "2018-04-17"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                    weather = c("clear","storming","windy")) )

( Event_data = data.frame(event_date=as.Date(c("2017-06-03","2017-10-18", "2018-01-19"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                        cars_sold=c(2,3,7)) )
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: You guys are AMAZING!  This worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SQL lets you do a between join that gets exactly the result you are looking for.

```
library(sqldf)

join <- sqldf(
  "SELECT L.Event_date, L.cars_sold, R.weather
  FROM Event_data as L
  LEFT JOIN Envir_data as R
  ON L.event_date BETWEEN R.envir_start_date AND R.envir_end_date"
  )
```

Comment: You guys are AMAZING! This worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We use `seq.Date` to generate a sequence of dates based on the data in `Envir_data`. It is important to use `rowwise` to only create a list based on the row grouping. This operation results in a list column. We then unnest that list column to have one row per date. Finally we join to the `Event_data`.

```
Envir_data_2 <- Envir_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(event_date = list(seq.Date(envir_start_date, envir_end_date,
                                    by = "day"))) %>%
  unnest(event_date) %>%
  select(event_date, weather)

Event_data %>%
  inner_join(Envir_data_2)

#   event_date cars_sold  weather
# 1 2017-06-03         2    clear
# 2 2017-10-18         3    clear
# 3 2018-01-19         7 storming
```

Comment: You guys are AMAZING! This worked perfectly, thank you.